# Difference between assigning a string literal to a char array at declaration vs to a char pointer?

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand why both :

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[8] = "Hello \n";
    write(1, buffer, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <unistd.h> 

int main()
{
   char buffer[8];
   char *ptr = buffer;
   ptr = "Hello \n";
   write(1, ptr, 7);
   return 0;
}
```

successfully output "Hello " to the console but

```
#include <unistd.h> 

int main()
{
   char buffer[8];
   char *ptr = buffer;
   ptr = "Hello \n";
   write(1, buffer, 7);
   retrun 0;
}
```

doesn't (instead it outputs gibberish) when I expect all three to be essentially the same.

I'm guessing there is something fundamentally wrong in my understanding of the relationship between pointers and arrays in `c` ...

Comment: A pointer stores the address of some memory. Changing the pointer does not change the contents of what it was pointing to. It just points it somewhere else. So in the last two examples the pointer is changed from pointing to the `buffer` memory to a string literal. The original `buffer` content is unchanged.

Comment: `buffer` and `ptr` are two different variables (with different types to boot). If you have two `int` variables, assigning a value to one of them will not affect the other.

Comment: A pointer variable can be used to affect the value of the thing being pointed at, but you must dereference the pointer to address the referenced object.

Comment: An array is an `rvalue`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin an array name is an lvalue.   (C doesn't have rvalues either, strictly speaking)

Comment: @M.M I was referring to 6.3.2.1 - "... an expression that has type *"array of type"* is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. ..." (so yes, "not an lvalue" would have been more proper than "rvalue")

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin lvalues can be converted to rvalues, which is what the text you quote is describing. It only happens in some contexts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're conflating a couple of different, unrelated issues here:

```
 char buffer[8];      // You're allocating 8 bytes: OK
 char *ptr = buffer;  // You're aliasing "ptr" to "&buffer[0]": OK
 ptr = "Hello \n";    // Now you're ASSIGNING ptr to a completely DIFFERENT address
 write(1, buffer, 7); // You never actually assigned any data to buffer
```

Suppose, instead, you did this:

```
 char buffer[8];      // Allocate 8 bytes
 char *ptr = buffer;  // Aliasing "ptr" to "&buffer[0]"
 strcpy(ptr, "Hello \n"); // Now you've actually assigned data
 write(1, buffer, 7); /. You should no longer see "garbage" ;)
```

In other words, this issue isn't so much "pointers vs. arrays"; it's really "correctly initializing whatever it is you're pointing to".

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks a lot. I guess I didn't understand how string literals worked more so than pointers...